# Error: there is no package called ‘vctrs’

Tags: r

When I try to run these lines, I keep getting the issue below- any way to resolve this?? Thanks!

```
pkgs<-c('lmerTest', 'ggplot2')
suppressMessages(lapply(pkgs, require, character.only = TRUE))
require(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
require(interactions)
library(ggplot2)
require(apaTables)
library(apaTables)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lmerTest’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘vctrs’
```

Comment: What version of R are you using? Try running `install.packages("vctrs")`

Comment: Read the DESCRIPTION file of pkg lmer. You have at least one  unmet dependency. And next time search before posting.

Comment: the dependency is deep, though: `lmerTest` imports `ggplot2` imports `tibble` imports `vctrs` ...

Answer (score 2):

Try to install vctrs from github and this helped in my case.

```
install.packages("vctrs", repos = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/latest")
```

Comment: That's enough just to write `install.packages("vctrs")`